# Which tool to use for creating visual illustrations in poetry book?

Tags: tools, artwork

I am working on ebook that is a collection of poems. I want to create illustrations according to poem (similar to something shown in below image). But I don't know which tool to use. I tried Amazon Create but it doesn't have option of adding illustrations. Please recommend tools that a novice can use (I am not a graphic designer and no experience for adobe indesign and photoshop)

[image]

Comment: Let's distinguish creating (drawing) the illustrations and editing them into the document. Usual editing programs have either no or extremely bad drawing tools, but they allow importing images created with external tools and placing them within the document.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas...accessible support, tons of templates, illustrations...many of them @ $0.00. 
I hope this helps! Best of luck to you!! - Sally Clark

CANVA:
Website - https://www.canva.com/
• Search result for “poetry ebook:”
https://www.canva.com/search/templates?q=poetry%20ebook
• Canva app - https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1273965205

CREATIVE MARKET:
Website - https://creativemarket.com/tags/nf/ebook-design

Answer (score 1):

For me it all depends on the content of the poems.

- If it's classically philosophical poems, you might want something sober, reflecting the general style of your poems.
- If it's more experimental poetry, you might want abstract art or photography to illustrate your thoughts and feelings while writing the poems.

But after all, it's **your** art, your **poetry**, your **work**. Feel it out and see what you want.